Tabulator : persist column order but not titles
Is it possible to persist column order when you define a list of column properties to be persisted ?
According to the documentation, this will persist order, title, width and visiblity :
columns: true

And this will persist width and visibility :
columns: ["width", "visible"]

How can I persist order without titles, or order with additional properties ?

The following should work for your case, just persisting the field, which is needed anyway to link the order back to the column:
columns: ["field"]


I went for <columns: ["width", "visible", "field"]>, it seems to be working, thanks !
